Can we identify max last used value of sequence in oracle
I have a requirement, where we have 2 tables(lets say tab1 & tab2) and one sequence(seq1) is being used for both the tables.
for 1st run; 5 records are inserted in tab1 so for primary key column(col_tab1) using seq1.nextval 1 to 5 are created,
now for 2nd run; another 5 records are inserted to tab2 and for its primary key column(col_tab2) again using seq1.nextval 6 to 10 are created,
following above process data are randomly inserted into tab1 and tab2.
till now I was considering max of col_tab1 or col_tab2 to insert data. but due to increase in data size just wanted to understand if there is any way that we can check for last seq value used.

You can certainly read seq1.currval but I'm not sure that's the question. You mention something about maximums but don't think you're explaining your goal.

@ÁlvaroGonzález, you can, but only in the same session (when you already used that sequence). In a new session, you'd get ORA-08002: sequence SEQUENCE_NAME.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session

Curious as to why you would require this info ?
